# How to remove jQuery .focusOut function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element that has focusOut event apilied to it:

```
$('selector').focusout(function() {           
});
```

later i need that function removed. I tried:

```
$('selector').off('focusout');
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Any advices??

(I can't get around this, ive tried i need it removed)

Thx in advance :D

EDIT:

im useing Jquery 1.8.3

Unfortunate i can't provide fidle because I'm useing proprietary framework that has some private
html tags and fidle can't read trough it

Comment: Have you tried .stop()?  Or . clearQueue()?

Comment: Which jquery version are you using?

Comment: @Myles .stop() and clearQueue() are not event's method

Comment: Could you provide your full code? Possibly a fiddle?

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` can help you

Comment: @RajarshiDas What default behaviour this will prevent?

Comment: if you are using jquery 1.7+ I can´t see why it should not work did a test: http://jsfiddle.net/Ybndz/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way I can re-create your problem is with jquery 1.6.4 or below if you are using this you need to do it like this:

```
$('selector').bind('focusout', function() {

});

$('selector').unbind('focusout');
```

Comment: `bind` is deprecated and has been replaced with `on`/`off` See [here](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) `As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('selector').unbind('focusout');
```

Comment: In order to unbind it needs to have been bound in the first place, which in this case it was not.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("selector").unbind("focusout");
```